# SSIS and ADO.NET and Azure

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to move a table into SQL Azure using SSIS.  I have an ADO.NET source and destination, but when I run it it always fails with an error relating to IDENTITY INSERT being off.  From other posts it mentioned i should remove the check from the box "Use Bulk Insert when possible".  I have and still receive the same error.  Any ideas on how to move over IDENTITY columns into SQL Azure?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by the message, the destination has an identity field, so you have two oprtions:

- change the ADO destination to an OLEDB destination and check the
  "keep identity" check box on your destination component
- manually set identity_insert ON on the table you are trying to insert
  records.

Comment: Thanks,  I had read that OLEDB did not work with Azure,  and from my first attempt I found that to be true.  I tried again this time with a different provider and all went fine..

Comment: @GregTyndall which provider did you use?